# How do I declare a constant variable with a value of a function call

Tags: vba, ms-access, constants

In a VBA module I have the following declaration of constants:

```
Private Const const_abc  =  3000
Private Const const_def  =   900
Private Const const_etc  =    42
'  and so on and so forth
```

Now, I have to initialize these values with a *one time* function call, ideally something like so

```
Private Const const_abc = someFunc(18)
Private Const const_def = someFunc( 7)
Private Const const_etc = someFunc( 5)
'  and so on and so forth
```

Of course, this won't work in VBA. So, is there a common pattern on how to deal with such a requirement?

I probably could go like so

```
Private const_abc As Double
Private const_def As Double
Private const_etc As Double

sub initConsts()
    const_abc = someFunc(18)
    const_def = someFunc( 7)
    const_etc = someFunc( 5)
end sub
```

But then I'd have to make sure that `initConsts` is called which I'd rather not do.

**Edit** As per the question of *S O*, I am using MS-Access.

Comment: Which application are you working with?

Comment: @SO, is it matter? VBA is VBA no matter of application...

Comment: @SO, I am using Access.

Comment: Constants need to be evaluable at *compile time* - you cannot assign them values from functions.  Otherwise, they are just regular global variables. What is the best approach to use depends on the cost of assigning the values: if it's low-cost then you might be better off making them into functions, so you'll always get the required value.

Comment: A constant is just that: constant. Its value cannot be changed during the execution of code.

Comment: @TimWilliams I understand that, the problem is that I *already have* some code with constants that I *now (as per new requirement)* have to initialize with the value of a function. Turns out that in such a case having constants with VBA causes me some unforseen problems.

Comment: Then maybe it would help to explain exactly what those problem are.

Comment: *as per new requirement* - Then they need to change to no longer be constants, as they no longer contain constant values, but are changing at runtime based on the function call.

Comment: @MaciejLos because different applications have different events that can or cannot be exposed in different objects (i.e. database using `AutoExec()` vs. Workbook using `Workbook_Open()`)

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger why _don't_ you want to call `initConsts` ? That seems to be the logical approach.

Comment: @KenWhite As I have pointed out in my question this is what I have already done, but now I'd have to call an `initVars()` procedure for every application that uses these variables formerly known as constants, and I'd rather not do that.

Comment: I don't see as how you have any choice. If the variable needs to be set to the result of a function call, it is no longer a constant. The function call only happens at the time of execution of the code, and therefore the value is variable. Variables have to be initialized somewhere when the code executes - they can't just magically obtain the proper values.

Comment: @KenWhite if this be the case, then so be it, but it seems that VBA is about the only language I have come accross that has such a limitation, so I was not sure if I am overlooking something.

Comment: "Limitation"? It's not a limitation; it's intentional design. *Constants* are designed to be just that - *constant*, meaning not changing in value) -, and *variables* are designed to have their values change (vary). Almost every language differentiates between them, as does an English language dictionary. They're named according to their intended use. There's no limitation - it's a designed construct.

Comment: _" for every application that uses these variables"_ - I'm not sure what you mean here, as the code would be contained in the single instance of the Application it's being run from. In which case you could merely change the scope of the variables to `Public` or `Global` and use them throughout?

Comment: @SO the file with these variables/constants is shared among a few applications. These applications use the `VBE` interface to load the file into the module collection of access. These applications access functions in the shared file that in turn depend on these variables/constants.

Comment: If you have VBE access enabled, you could configure the constants in a VBS file and then directly write the constants to the module using the `Application.VBE` object or setting a reference to it. Other than that I'd suggest creating a Class Module instead, using the `Class_Initialize()` method and set the private variables, then just use a `Property Get()` method to expose them as read-only. Either way I think your problem here is actually regarding _scope_ and not around _variable vs. constant_

Comment: Lovely, constants that are not constant. You should be able to see the dilemma. What you need is variables - as explained in detail by Ken White.

Comment: @Gustav, I already have stated the dilemma already and what the problem is that comes with it - in fact, I have even written so in my question. I am not sure if you and Ken White are aware that there are languages that allow to initialize constants with a call to a function. Since I only do VBA occasionally, I hoped that VBA is able to such a thing too, and if it can't I still consider this as a limitation.

Comment: OK, I haven't seen such language, so you may be right. However, the only reason for not just use variables instead should be, that these somehow could be changed from "uncontrolled" code. Though very unlikely, if this should be your concern, wrap them in a class as in the example from Peter.

Comment: In support of René, JavaScript, to take one popular example, has a `const` keyword that declares a variable whose value is assigned once and _then_ cannot change.  `const` is used far more often than `let` (or the old `var`) variables that can change.

Also, you can assign any expression to a const, it is a run-time const, not a compile-time const.

In VBA, I can't even do `const White = RGB(255, 255, 255)`, which any sane person would think was sensible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Public Function White() as Long
   White = RGB(255,255,255)
End function

Private Sub TestIt()
   Debug.Print "White is " & White
   White = 123       ' <-- compile error
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a class that reads the cell and presents a `Get`-only interface to the value.

Here's a class called `ItsMyValueClass`

Option Explicit

```
Private pMyVal As Integer

Public Property Get MyValue() As Integer
    MyValue = pMyVal
End Property

Private Sub class_initialize()
    'pMyVal = Sheet.Range("somewhere)
    pMyVal = 17
End Sub
```

And here's the code in your module:

```
Option Explicit

Sub IsItReadOnly()
    Dim valu As ItsMyValueClass
    Dim x As Integer
    Set valu = New ItsMyValueClass
    x = valu.MyValue
    'valu.MyValue = 23   'compile error "Can't assign to read-only property"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

in a **one-liner that works with modules and classes** alike for pure constant-like access:

```
Public Property Get myConst() As Integer:  myConst = 3:  End Property
```

you would use it like this:

```
Sub test()
    Debug.Print "myConst: " & myConst  'would print: "myConst: 3"
End Sub
```

and **if it has to be initialized with a custom value once**, one could do it with a static property and one or many private variables:

```
Private ci As Boolean  'constants initialized

Private myConst1_ As Integer
Private myConst2_ As Integer


Static Property Get myConst1() As Integer
    If Not ci Then init
    myConst1 = myConst1_
End Property


Static Property Get myConst2() As Integer
    If Not ci Then init
    myConst2 = myConst2_
End Property


Private Sub init()
    'these can come from anywhere:
    myConst1_ = 3  
    myConst2_ = 5 
    ci = True 
End Sub
```

- they are initialized on the first access of the first "constant" property
- if you have to initialize them earlier one could just call the `init` function earlier (and optionally remove the `ci` variable and all related lines if it is ensured that the properties are not accessed earlier)