Private Const oFolder as Folder
I have several functions and subs (appoximately 7) that use the following two lines.
Dim oFolder As Folder
Set oFolder = Application.Session.Folders("Rings").Folders("Contacts").Folders("Customers")

I'd like to create a Private Constant for the module to take the place of those two lines. I've tried Private Const oFolder as Folder = Application.Session.Folders("Rings").Folders("Contacts").Folders("Customers"), but that gives me a compile error: Expected: type name.
Is this even possible?

The best alternative would be to create a function called oFolder and have it return the value you want.

Constants are assigned at compile-time, so any assignment which is not evaluable except at run-time will get flagged.  See previously: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29614384/how-do-i-declare-a-constant-variable-with-a-value-of-a-function-call

Creating the below function worked great.  Didn't think about this route when I posted the question.
Private Function CustomerFolder() As Folder
  Set CustomerFolder = Application.Session.Folders("Rings").Folders("Contacts").Folders("Customers")
End Function


No, it is not possible - you have a sequence of methods calls, not a constant variable. Unless you create a function that takes a string, parses it, and then opens the folders recursively. You can then hardcode the function argument - a string like "\\Rings\Contacts\Customers"

Per the Documentation, Constants can be declared as: Byte, Boolean Integer, Long, Currency, Single, Double, Decimal¹, Date, String, or Variant`
Note, first, that Folder is not in that list — so, no, it is not possible.
Note, second, that those are all Data Types that you assign values to, and not ones that you Set to an Object Reference.  So, no, it's doubly not possible — because Folder is an object type, not a value type.

¹ Decimal Constants are not supported in all versions of Visual Basic, so I would advise sticking with Single or Double instead
